# Rally Rest API Query Project not returning all Projects

Tags: rally

I have been using this function for some time but it has recently broke. When I query for all Projects I do not get them all. Some are parents and some are child projects and all projects in the workspace are open. I do get them all when I use the Rally examples but not with the .Net implementation. I do not see any difference between the Projects that would cause some to not show up in my query.
I am using Ver 1.43 but it does the same in Ver 2.0.

```
            Request req = new Request("project");

            //Get a list of fetch items from the stucture
            req.Fetch = getFetchListFromStruct(typeof(struct_ProjectFields));

            //Run the Query
            QueryResult qr = restAPI.Query(req);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you set a limit on your request?  You may have finally crossed over the maximum page size and that may be why all the projects are not being returned.

```
req.Limit = 1000;
```